# Unable to enter the string "echo "$(cat test.txt)"" in system()

Tags: c

This is what I want to do

```
system("echo "$(cat test.txt)"");
```

i.e I want to pass the command: echo "$(cat test.txt)"  to system().

But keeps giving me compilation  error :

```
init.c: In function 'main':
init.c:19:3: error: 'echo' undeclared (first use in this function)
init.c:19:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
init
```

The argument of system is not becoming a constant string, even after putting double qoutes.

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Escape the inner quotes

```
system("echo \"$(cat test.txt)\"");
```